# Get all file names in a directory ignoring file extension

Tags: c#, file-extension

I have a folder with files like this:

```
foo.map
foo.ind
foo.dat
bar.map
bar.ind
bar.dat
readme.txt
readme.html
```

I like to get all distinct file names but without extension, i.e. `foo, bar, readme`.

Of course I can use `Directory.GetFiles()` and make a loop with `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` but I wonder if there is a short way, maybe just one line, e.g. using LINQ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
directory
    .GetFiles()
    .Select(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.Name))
    .Distinct();
```

Comment: missing the .Distinct()